# Make responsive larger image of a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a responsive email template, with a letter that gets it out from an envelope.

The letter is smaller than the envelope and I can't resize it in the same way as the div.
If I put `width: 100%` on the envelope, I get the same div resize so not good.
If I put  `margin-left: -50px;`, it gets to the right on the left, but on the right the envelope remains on default size and div resize.

I am using bootstrap for grid system.

This is the template: http://www.kakaostudio.it/newsletter_v1/index_test.html

And this is the final result: [image: final result image]

Comment: Bootstrap grid system will not work inside emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brute force approach would be as follows, this will give you a good idea on how to proceed.

```
.envelop img {
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: -60px;
width: 113%;
}
.envelop {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

By doing this you're giving the envelop a bigger width so it matches the div above it. Then move it to the left with negative margin-left.

I have a 1920px width screen and it shows perfectly in sync for me, but it's not responsive with this approach. You'd need to use many media queries to adjust the size as it goes.

You can try playing around with negative % for the margin-left or even better the "vw" values. Position: relative and a negative value for left will give you the same result as margin-left.

[Image](https://i.gyazo.com/2a3baa068f62d8e6c7a44f33e2ccb5b4.png) of my approach's result.